# Husky: git commit --amend and push inside a pre-push hook

Tags: bash, githooks, husky

In order to make a continuous improvement script, inside my `pre-push` hook, I am trying to add a `jest.config.js` when it is changed, `git commit --amend` it, and push it:

```bash
git add ${PROJECT_ROOT}/jest.config.js
git commit --amend -C HEAD
git pull
git push --no-verify
```

However, because this code is in a pre-push hook, that means that the push that should happen afterwards will fail because:

```
remote: error: cannot lock ref 'my/branch': is at 'updatedHash' but expected 'formerHash'
```

Is there a recommended way to push inside a pre-push hook?

Comment: Did you ever figure out a way to achieve this?

Comment: Sorry but no, I ended up giving up :/

Comment: You know what, i just tried doing git add and git commit without the git push. It works fine, it is added to the files being pushed to the remote.

Comment: Is it being pushed to the last commit, including the amend? If so, you can answer the question and I'll validate your answer!

Comment: Yeah it seems like it, i tried it and my changes were part of the last commit and got pushed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was facing the same issue, after playing with it i figured out that we don't need to "re-push" we can just commit with `--amend` and it will be part of the last commit and will get pushed.

For example:

```
git add ${PROJECT_ROOT}/jest.config.js
git commit --amend --no-edit
```

Note that i changed your `-C` (which is `--reuse-message`) to `--no-edit` but i guess you can also use `-C` in this case, though i'm not sure about the implications.